# Finding the partial derivatives of $h(x)=\int_{0}^{\|x\|} f(t)\, dt$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Find the partial derivatives of $$h(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\int_{0}^{\|x\|} f(t) dt$$ where $\|x\|$ is the Euclidean norm of $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $f$ is some continuous function.

I'm sorry but I'm really not too sure how to approach this. Any help would be great!

(This is not homework, I'm preparing for an exam.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $$F(s) = \int^{b(s)}_{a(s)}f(t)dt,$$
then
$$F'(s) = b'(s)f(b(s))-a'(s)f(a(s)).$$
In particular if $$b(s) = \|(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},s,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)\|_2 \quad \text{ and } \quad a(s)=0,$$
then
$$b'(s) = \frac{s}{\|(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},s,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)\|_2} \quad \text{ and } \quad a'(s)=0,$$
It follows that 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} h(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},s,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n) = F'(s) =  \frac{s f(\|(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},s,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)\|_2)}{\|(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},s,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)\|_2}.$$
which can be written 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} h(x) = \frac{x_i}{\|x\|_2}f(\|x\|_2),$$
with $s=x_i$.

Comment: Great detailed answer, infinite thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$ \newcommand{\pd}[2]{ \frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2} } $ 
**Hint:** (see [**here**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Proofs) for more information or the good answer provided by @Surb)

$$\small{\pd{}{x_1} \int^{\sqrt{x_1^2 +x_2^2 +\ldots + x_n^2}}_0f(s)\, \mathrm{d}s = f\left(\sqrt{x_1^2 +x_2^2 +\ldots + x_n^2}\right) \frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2 +x_2^2 +\ldots + x_n^2}} = \frac{f(\|x\|)}{\| x \|}x_1,}$$

can you generalize the result for any $x_i$? Sure you can.

Cheers!

Comment: Excellent, thank you sir!

Comment: You're welcome @rehband. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d}{dx_{j}}=\frac{d\parallel x\parallel }{dx_{j}}\frac{d}{d\parallel
x\parallel }=\frac{x_{j}}{\parallel x\parallel }\frac{d}{d\parallel
x\parallel }
\end{equation*}